# How to query from a Rails variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, paperclip

I'm using Rails 3.2 then I have a query that uses find_by_sql:

```
@posts ||= Post.all_post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

How do I get all the post id from @posts using Rails? I have to get all the ids using activerecord not find_bys_sql. I was thinking that maybe I can just query from the @posts variable.

My situation is, I need the active record query for paperclip but my query for @posts is quite complex so I need to use find_by_sql. If I only rely on association to get the images for paperclip its a lot of round trip against the db so I plan to get all the ids by doing just one query not association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get array of ids from Object of Post:--

```
ids = @posts.map(&:id).flatten

1.9.3-p385 :022 > ids = @posts.map(&:id).flatten
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166]
```

Comment: Hi! I have to query from the variable @posts not from the Post model again.